# Android: ADB not loading

Tags: android

When I want to create android project I get the following message. I cant proceed anyway. Please anybody help me. My system is ubuntu 10.10

Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/mak/Android/Android SDK/android-sdk-linux_x86/platform-tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied

Comment: refresh that android sdk from net is better

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the /home volume is mounted without the exec permission.  Examine your /etc/fstab.